# Issue with bootstrap toggle menu working in chrome but not when loaded on mobile safari

Tags: togglebutton

I have combed through compatibility issues on this site looking for fixes for this problem and I cannot seem to find any posts with quite the same issue as me.

Basically, when I load the app in chrome browser and inspect through all phone sizes, it is responsive and it works.  However when I actually open the app web address in my personal iphone, the toggle menu does not work.  It drops down behind the main content and is hardly clickable.  Can anyone help?
Here is a link to the app:
https://evening-stream-86674.herokuapp.com/index.html

Here is the portion of the CSS file:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

html {
    height: 100%;

}

body {
    background: url("../images/tree.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover; 
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

/*my favorite lime green color #47dd1b*/



li {
    background-color: black;
}


.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    height: 8%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
li {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">John Wolfe</a>
            </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>

<div id="wrap">
```

Edited to show less code.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code the a minimum amount needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: done.  thanks for taking a look.